# printer installed, not printing

Tags: canon, pixma

I am trying to print, even run a test print, the printer is showing in "printers" with the green circle and tick beside it, but nothing is happening

Comment: Please add results from  `lpstat -t`  to the question (that will show status of printer and print queue). Also to try: ping the printer from command line and see if it responds.